# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency Props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

In my react/redux app, i have an action that gets called to retrieve data from state in redux each time the component is mounted. My way does not work

Below is the error I'm getting:

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will
> change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure
> the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those
> specific props inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Here is my code:

```
import { getInvoiceData } from "../../actions/tables"

const TableSection = (props) =>{

  useEffect(() => {
    props.getInvoiceData();
  }, []);


  const classes = useStyles();

(...)

TableSection.propTypes = {
  invoiceData: PropTypes.object
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  invoiceData: state.tables.invoiceData,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getInvoiceData })(TableSection);
```

Comment: bro the is a hooks for react-redux why using connect intsead use `useSelector` and `useDispatch`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the mechanisms of ``useSelector`` or ``useDispatch``, Maybe you could demonstrate with the above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependency array you pass to `useEffect()` is empty, but you're using `props. getInvoiceData()` inside of it, so it's missing the `props`. Add it like this:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    props.getInvoiceData();
  }, [props]);
```

Better would be to deconstruct your props:

```js
const TableSection = ({invoiceData , getInvoiceData}) =>{

  useEffect(() => {
   getInvoiceData();
  }, [getInvoiceData]);
  
  // Use invoiceData here
  console.log(invoiceData);
```

Dependencies are used to let `useEffect()` know if it should fire again or not. Since your `getInvoiceData` is function, in this case it will only fire once, just like `componentDidMount()`.

Comment: Then, how best to use **invoiceData** props that's coming from the redux state when using the deconstructor you used?

Comment: Updated the answer to include invoiceData. This works with any props you pass to the component, either by its parent or redux

Comment: It would be good to wrap the ```props.getInvoiceData();``` with local function.

Comment: I think accepted answer should be changed to the one with useSelector and useDispatch hooks. Because @Emre-Koc's answer is not the best practice. Including the functions inside the dependency array would result the function to be redeclared on each render. Which is not ideal when you are not able to wrap it by useCallback or declare the function inside the useEffect. you need to memoize the function reference somehow. See: [related official react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies)

Answer (score 3):

using react-redux hooks like `useSelector` and `useDispatch` will minimize your work time, here your code with react-redux hooks:

```
import { getInvoiceData } from "../../actions/tables"
import {useSelector ,useDispatch} from "react-redux"

const TableSection = (props) =>{
const {invoiceData} = useSelector(state=>state.tables)
const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getInvoiceData())
  }, []);


  const classes = useStyles();

return (<div>
{// here do something with invoiceData}
{invoiceData && invoiceData.map(...)}
</div>)
}
TableSection.propTypes = {
  invoiceData: PropTypes.object
};

export default TableSection;
```